# Regex for failing if '^' is found?

Tags: regex

I have a regex for slicing off the first integer part of a string

```
(^[0-9]+)|(^\-[0-9]+)
```

i.e. with `'12x'`, slicing it would return `'12'`. I want to expand it so that it fails if there is a `'^'` in the string. I tried using a negative lookahead

```
(?!\^)(^[0-9]+)|(^\-[0-9]+)
```

but this doesn't work as it still matches e.g. `'12^x'`. I also tried it without the `'\'` before the `'^'` but it didn't match anything. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your current negative lookahead:

```
(?!\^)
```

The problem with this lookahead is that it uses the wrong pattern to achieve what you want.  It is only looking ahead one character, which mean it can't check the entire string until the end for the presence or absence of a carat.

```
^(?!.*\^)-?[0-9]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^(?!.*\^)    from the start of the string, look ahead and assert that no carat appears
-?[0-9]+$    match an optional minus sign, followed by any number of digits
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about `?` in regex it's super useful. That works perfectly although I still want it to match with strings that don't just contain integers, so I just took the `$` off the end.

Comment: @user6731064 That wasn't clear to me, if removing the `$` fixes your problem, then by all means do it.

Comment: *Furthermore, you have it placed before the start of the regex* - this ~~doesn't~~ shouldn't(?) matter; they're both zero-width assertions that should be able to appear in either order.

Comment: @Rawling Verified, and I just [learned something new about regex](https://regex101.com/r/3tzYWJ/2).